# Slingshot Woods - 1

Tags: angry-birds-epic

I cannot complete Slingshot Woods - 1. The battle is with a huge zombie-type pig. No matter what I try, I always lose. I've been stuck on this level for a whole week. Can somebody help me?

[image: Worst Level Ever]